# Adding validation in jsp page its working still showing some errors in console

Tags: javascript, java, validation, jsp

Hello i am adding validation in my JSP page its working but still its showing errors in console  as null exception.

this is the function that i have prepared for validation

```
function countriesInfo(){
             var a = document.forms["countries"]["countryname"].value;
            var x = document.forms["countries"]["description"].value;
            if (a == null || a == "") {
                alert("Name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
            if(x.length > 2000){
                alert("Description should be maximum of 2000 characters");
                return false;
            }//else{
                //return true;
                //}
        }
```

Following is my JSP page form

```
<form name="countries"action="/RouternData/roternInternal" method="post"  onsubmit="return countriesInfo()">
                <input type='hidden'  value='YES' name='SAVECONTRYDETAILS' /> 
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Enter countries detail</h2></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table1" border="0">
                        <tbody>


                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i></span>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" Enter country name" name="countryname" id="countryName" required>

                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon" ><i class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></i></span>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" placeholder="Country description" name="description" id="countrydescription" ></textarea>

                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >


                                 </td>
                                 <td >
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="saveCountry()" > Submit</button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">reset</button>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>

this is the error that i am getting
numberFormatException:  null
```

hollowing is the controller code

```
private static void saveCountryDetails(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String countryname = request.getParameter(CountryConstant.COUNTRYNAME);
        String description = request.getParameter(CountryConstant.DESCRIPTION);

         //CountryDetail cd = new CountryDetail(); creates an instance to relate with the bean file CountryDetail.

        CountryDetail cd = new CountryDetail();
        cd.setCountryname(countryname);
        cd.setDescription(description);

        RouternHibernateConfigManager.persistObject(cd);

         // RequestDispatcher dispatches request to the desired page after inserting the data.

        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("jspfiles/countries.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

        // retriveCountryDetails(request, response);

    }
```

following is the bean file code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COUNTRYDETAIL")
public class CountryDetail {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CountryId", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer countryid;
    //@Lob
    //@Column(name = "COUNTRYFLAG" , columnDefinition ="mediumblob")
    //private byte[] countryFlag ;
    @Column(name = "CountryName", nullable = false)
    private String countryname;
    @Column(name = "Description", nullable = false , length = 2000)
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="countryid")
    private List<StateDetail> stateDetails;

    /**
     * @return the stateDetails
     */

    public List<StateDetail> getStateDetails() {
        return stateDetails;
    }

    /**
     * @param stateDetails the stateDetails to set
     */
    public void setStateDetails(List<StateDetail> stateDetails) {
        this.stateDetails = stateDetails;
    }

    /**
     * @return the countryid
     */

    // @TableGenerator(name ="cid" , table ="ctab" , pkColumnName = "ckey" ,
    // pkColumnValue =" cvalue" , allocationSize =1)

    public Integer getCountryid() {
        return countryid;
    }

    /**
     * @param countryid
     *            the countryid to set
     */
    public void setCountryid(Integer countryid) {
        this.countryid = countryid;
    }

    /**
     * @return the countryname
     */

    public String getCountryname() {
        return countryname;
    }

    /**
     * @param countryname
     *            the countryname to set
     */
    public void setCountryname(String countryname) {
        this.countryname = countryname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the description
     */

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * @param description
     *            the description to set
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }





}
```

Comment: Did you fill any value for the `description` input?

Comment: i had fill the description as well as country name as shown here that if the description limit exceeds by 2000 character it will show the message same thing is happening but i am getting errors in console also have put validation in country name so that it does not  show null nut its showing null  also in database i have kept there field as not null.

Comment: Can you show the controller code that handles your form `POST` action?

Comment: i have added the controller and the bean file code

Comment: If you debug your controller, does the `description` filled with any value? Is your `CountryConstant` matches with the form field name?

Comment: ya when i am running my page adding value in it i am getting the correct message that i want but still its showing errors.

Comment: CountryConstant is not any variable its a java file where i have created constant for all the strings so that the same name strings do not initialize again and again

Comment: So in your controller you've got all the input data are correct? Is your database in a Linux machine, there might be case sensitive issue with the field names?

Comment: no its not a linux machine i am using mac os x and for database i am using mysql workbench

Comment: if i have to use stop propagation and prevent default function here how should i use it